# Changing the button style of certain buttons in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, button, datagridview, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I have a DataGridView with a Button column in it.

I want to be able to disable and enable the buttons in every row (and/or change the style of them), according to a cell value in the row.

So let's say we have the following code :

```
if(dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString()=="OK")
        {
            //button in the same row should be enabled or disabled
        }
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit a `DataGridViewDisableButtonCell` class from `DataGridViewButtonCell` to use in your DGV, as [explained on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171619.aspx). Then you'll be able to enable/disable the button inside that cell with the following code:

```
DataGridViewDisableButtonCell buttonCell = (DataGridViewDisableButtonCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Buttons"];
buttonCell.Enabled = myEnableConditionMet ? true : false;
```